# Swift: How to read multiple array within array in plist?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, plist

This is my plist

Collections View

[image: pic1]

With Swift 3, I'm reading the plist to fill my arrays with this code perfectly but I do not know how to access the plist when it has arrays inside the root array

The code I use to read when the root is an array

```
var mainGroup = [String]()

var myArray: [String]?
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "items", ofType: "plist") {
    myArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String]
}

mainGroup = myArray!
```

But in this plist, theres more arrays to read than just the root. I would like to read how many arrays the root has so in my collection view I use it in `numberOfItemsInSection`, `cellForItemAt` and `didSelectItemAt`. And I would like to also read items inside the arrays to display it in detail view of the collections for when an item is selected.

Conclusion: I want to read how many arrays are in root array to use it in `.count` and how to access the items in the arrays to display it in another view controller as detail. To access an array it would be `array[2]` but how would that work if I wanted to display the string "Jeans" and "4" , etc. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended way in Swift to read a property list file is `PropertyListSerialization`. It avoids the usage of Foundation `NSArray`.

The code prints the section numbers and all items in the inner array.

If the property list is is supposed to populate a table view I recommend to declare the inner array as dictionary.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"items", withExtension: "plist")!
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf:url)
    let sections = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [[Any]]

    for (index, section) in sections.enumerated() {
        print("section ", index)
        for item in section {
            print(item)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("This error must never occur", error)
}
```

Comment: how would I grab an item inside the array of my choice and print it? I know i can append it to an array but it would be complicated to get the index

Comment: Arrays are index based. You can get an item with `section[2]`. But as mentioned in the answer it's more suitable to use a dictionary (key / value pairs)

Comment: Fantastic answer! Worked straight out of the box. To answer BroSimple - you can access, for example, the 2nd element of the 5th array in the file as sections[4][1]  - sections[4] returns an array in the 5th position (starting from 0) and then the [1] suffix fetches the 2nd element from that array.

Answer (score 2):

I have added comment respectively with rootArray & subArray
[image]

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        readPlist()
    }
    func readPlist(){
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SampleData", ofType: "plist")
        let rootArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)!
        print(rootArray.count)//Gives count for total objects. You can use in number of rows

        for data in rootArray {
            let subArray = data as? NSArray ?? []
            print(subArray.count)//Gives you subarray count
            for value in subArray {
                print("objects are \(value)")//Gives you contains of subarray
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ParsePlist {
    let plistName:String

    init(name:String) {
        plistName = name
    }

    func sectionArrayFromPlist() -> [[Any]]? {

        guard let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: plistName, ofType: "plist") else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let rootArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: plistPath) as? [Any] else {
            return nil
        }

        var sectionArray:[[Any]]?
        sectionArray = rootArray.flatMap({ $0 as? [Any]})
        return sectionArray
    }
}
```

use:

```
let parsePlist = ParsePlist(name: <yourplistname>)
if let sectionArray = parsePlist.sectionArrayFromPlist() {
   // use sectionArray
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess that you make a mistake in data structure.Maybe you can try the code below...

```
var mainGroup = [[Any]]()

var myArray: [[Any]]?
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "items", ofType: "plist") {
    myArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
}

if let myArr = myArray {
   mainGroup = myArr
}
```

Comment: what would this code do? allow me to access the arrays within the root array?

Comment: 1. The plist is not an array of array of String. 2. Don't needlessly force-unwrap optionals.

Comment: You should either fix your answer or delete it.

Comment: Any other question?